# change color of setHeaderTitle onCreateContextMenu

Tags: android, colors

I would like to change the color of `setHeaderTitle` because the default is pink.Could you please tell me how?

```
menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose");
```

I know that if i change `colorAccent`
 from

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

it works but it changes many colors of my app of course.

Here is the full code

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_general, menu);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to change color of the ActionBar programmatically**

**ActionBar:**

> The action bar appears at the top of an activity

If this is your use-case you can follow this method.
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#5e9c00")));

Answer (score 0):

**This is how to change the color of setHeaderTitle onCreateContextMenu in the RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#D1BA88")), 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
menu.setHeaderTitle(spannableString);
```